# mysql select query optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql select query optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29182/mysql-select-query-optimization)

I have two tables, `testa` and `testb`.

```
CREATE TABLE `testa` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `testb` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid1` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid2` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid3` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Currently I am running the below query for retrieving all rows where id in `testa` table matches with any columns of `aid1`, `aid2`, `aid3` in `tableb`. The query returns the accurate result but it is taking minimum 30 seconds to execute which is too much. I have also tried to optimise my query using UNION but failed to do so.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, b.id 
FROM testb b 
INNER JOIN testa a ON b.aid1 = a.id OR b.aid2 = a.id OR b.aid3 = a.id ;
```

How do I optimize my query so it's total execution time is within 2-3 seconds?

Result of EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  b   ALL idx_aid1,idx_aid2,idx_aid3  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  10940   
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL PRIMARY (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  7512    Using where; Using join buffer
```